# What happened to King Canute

Tags: history

I was watching Downton Abbey season 4 episode 2.

The conversation goes like this:

> Violet Crawley: Now I asked Branson to come here because I have an
>   idea.
>   Mary Crawley: Granny, you must call him Tom.
>   Violet Crawley: I thought I could call him Branson again now that he's
>   the agent.
>   Mary Crawley: Well, you can't.
>   Tom Branson: I don't mind.
>   Violet Crawley: No. I see I'm beaten but, oh, how I sympathise with
>   King Canute.

Tom Branson was initially the family chauffeur, so was called Branson. Later he married Mary's sister Sybil, so Violet had to address him "Tom" as a family member.

Tom became the estate agent helping Mary's husband Matthew. Both Sybil and Matthew died before this conversion. In a sense Tom is again "working for" the family, so grandma Violet was trying to call him Branson again.

But, how come the whole thing is related to [King Canute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnut_the_Great)?

Comment: He started spelling his name _Knut_ and nobody ever heard of him again.

Comment: @JohnLawler is this a pun or ....?

Comment: It seems so incredibly strange to see the Dowager Countess referred to as “Violet”. In all the six seasons of this series, I do not believe _anyone_ called her that at any point! I’m sure she’d be absolutely horrified, had she not been dead for the better part of a century (and fictional).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet well in her twenties, I fancy Violet is a name lovely as she

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the English language, it is simply about understanding a cultural context and knowing something about the history of the UK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dowager Countess was just expressing that she felt as powerless to stop the rising tide of egalitarianism as King Canute was to [stop the rising of the tide](http://www.elizabethmolin.com/?p=206).

Answer (score 2):

It was the Dowager's frustration with her inability to stop the waves of change expressed by her reference to King Canute, who could not stop the waves.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it’s more an expression of the limits of her authority, however regretful that may be to her.  Remember, King Canute never actually thought he could stem the rising tide — it was never about arrogance.

As the story goes, he ordered his throne be carried to the water’s edge, where he commanded the waves to stop advancing in order to demonstrate to his advisers that there were even limits to the authority of a king.